# Formula for comparing the youth of different groups?

Tags: variance, measurement

For purely personal reasons, I recently tried to write a Ruby script that pulled information about various school rosters, counting the numbers of freshmen...seniors on the team and using that data to spit out some information about the teams relative youth based on the amount of eligibility left. As far as I am concerned, actual age is not an issue here.

The forumla I used was something simple:

```
eligibility = (FR * 4) + (SO * 3) + (JR * 2) + SR
average     = eligibility / (FR + SO + JR + SR)
```

Anyway, this is obviously a really simple formula. It doesn't put any weight on any one factor and the total eligibility number really doesn't tell me anything.

I was wondering if anyone had any better ideas when it came to realizing a formula for this issue. I'm not sure if this is the forum for this kind of question, but I became interested in the solution the other day and thought this might be a good place to look for an answer.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on what "eligibility" is in this situation?

Comment: @Andy W I believe he means "eligibility" in the sense that college athletes can play for up to four years. To the OP, it seems to be your measure, which is essentially "Average playing years left" seems as decent a way to measure it as anything.

Comment: @EpiGrad is correct! Freshmen have 4 years left, sophomores have 3... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems to be a reasonable one. If all teams are of the same size (I have no idea when this circumstance might be true), it reduces to just the sum of remaining years of eligibility, but your formula, the average number of years of play remaining, seems to be a reasonable one.

One could put more complicated spins on it, of course - the number of juniors for example, that are expected to continue on as seniors rather than getting snapped up by a pro league, or weighted by expected injury rates or the like - but these are both very sport and subject matter specific questions, and your formula can work well as a base.

Comment: I was thinking that this might be simplest way to come up with a ranking. Thanks!